# Change pricing in Woocommerce based on Category and Product

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am new to Woocommerce and PHP and I'm trying to create a product page exactly as on this site
http://www.singlesswag.com/subscribe

i.e. it should be a 2 step checkout. On the first page I can choose the box and pick my plan and the price should get updated accordingly. On the second page I can fill the checkout form and pay.

I have tried searching plugins for this conditional logic but couldn't find any where.

Is there a plugin for Woocommerce which can help me make this kind of product page or it is only possible by coding in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this page: http://singlesswag.com/subscribe as your single product page. On click of "proceed to payment" you are effectively adding the product to the basket with your selected options (a variable product) and going direct to checkout to fill in the form. You won't be able to get the desired effect as your example site without a little development knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To get to such a page, you can create variable products with multiple attributes.

With prices and features and ... different.

Of course, there's little need to change the design of the single-product page

[Variable Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/)

Comment: So I created a variable product named "test" as you can see on this link
http://mamaandpeaches.handyland.in/test/
When I click on the product it takes me to a new page where I can select the number of months.
So what I was looking for is I don't have to go to a new page to select the month as on http://www.singlesswag.com/subscribe. 
Is it possible to the exact checkout as on http://www.singlesswag.com/subscribe with variable products i.e select everything on the first page itself and fill the form and pay on the next page.

Comment: When you create a variable product, the user can not add it to the cart without entering the product page. Because he must first open the single product page and select one of the product attributes to the original student price